# Meteor won't recognize JS files for integration with a pre-built template

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

As the title states, I'm having some issues getting meteor to recognize Javascript files for a pre-built bootstrap template.

I've stepped through Manuel Schoebel's article - http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteorjs-and-twitter-bootstrap---the-right-way

and I've also read this helpful article - https://www.yauh.de/using-pre-made-themes-with-meteor/

on using pre-built themes with Meteor.

this post is from a guy that has been trying to integrate the same template as I am - [MeteorJS external files: css and js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641671/meteorjs-external-files-css-and-js)

He claims to have got it working with the following code:

```
Template.layout.rendered = function() {

      $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript"                 src="/javascript/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>');
  $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript"    src="/javascript/jquery.fittext.js"></script>');
  $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/wow.min.js"></script>');
  $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/creative.js"></script>');

}
```

Although placing in the client meteor code does not seem to fix the issue.
I have bootstrap and Jquery packages installed also.

I've tried adding links directly to the head, and have moved the files around to different areas (from client folder, to public etc).

these  are the errors I am getting in the browser console - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLNNp.png

this  is my current folder structure - https://i.stack.imgur.com/th7S0.png

Is it safe to assume that getting pre-built templates like this to work along side meteor is more effort than it is worth?

I'm quite new to this, and think converting them to meteor packages might be out the scope of my current skill level.

Am I able to copy the code into my meteor`.isclient()` area? I'm guessing its not going to be as simple as that.

I understand meteor does not work like conventional HTML, and packages are preferred. I just find it impossible to believe that I am not able easily use a bootstrap template that utilizes non-package js scripts.

Comment: According to Manuel's article you can enable the Bootstrap modules in client/vendor/custom.bootstrap.json. I don't see that file in you files tree.